# Can dd count md5 hash value on the fly in windows?

Tags: image, md5, dd, computer-forensics

I wrote a batch script for Windows 8 (64 bit) that creates images of USB Sticks with dd command using cygwin. Then I'm using md5 command to compare the hash values, but it takes a lot of time to read the image and usb again.

Are there any commands for Windows 64 bit to create the hash values on the fly during the imaging process?

Only dd is compatible with Win 64. The other dcfldd and FTKimager for command line are only available for Win32 bit.

Maybe you know something else?

Comment: I doubt that. The purpose of the hash value is to represent the integrity of the item it was created for. In the case of an image file it represents the whole image file (indirectly all items that are inside).

Comment: @rbaleksandar my problem that it takes a lot of time to count md5 separate. I ask if there are any other utilities for win64 to image and count md5 at the same time. It should command line utility

Comment: [This](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Dcfldd) perhaps can help?

Comment: There is also another version [here](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Dc3dd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit system.  The memory footprint of these tools should not require a 64-bit memory space. Are the 32-bit programs causing problems on your 64-bit system?

Comment: just tested it. I installed cygwin for 32 bit system and now dcfldd.exe works on my 64-bit system.  But dcfldd can only count md5 of the Image on the fly. Then i need to count md5 of my USB-Stick separate. It's not very convenient and takes extra time. It would be perfect if I could do it all together in one command

Comment: @Oleg_08 IDK about cygwin version, but native Linux version turns out to be really slow, nerfing performance of NVMe by order of magnitude. Perhaps it was ok For HDD / Flash drives. 

So it's faster to calculate checksum on separate iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not real code, but idea):

```
dd.exe if=/dev/xxx | tee.exe usb_disc.img | dd.exe of=/dev/yyy && md5sums.exe usb_disc.img && del usb_disc.img
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dc3dd (https://sourceforge.net/projects/dc3dd/) it can create hashes on-the-fly, while copying the data. I just stumbled upon this nice little tool and didn't test it yet. However, there is even a 64-Bit-Windows-Version (32 Bit doesn't seem to exist for windows). Could be exactly what you are looking for. Afaik dcfldd is generating hash-sums only on chunks (e.g. every 1 GB of data). dc3dd really generates a hash of the whole file.